# ngx-print doesn't Print AngularMaterial component Styles

Tags: angular, printing

I have Material Table With header and Footer cell in it. I am using ngx-print(**version - 1.2.1**)to print the table, If I add

> [useExistingCss]="true"

it Shows blank page or no style at all.and with

> styleSheetFile="custom.scss"

it is same issue.
I have Created Stakblitz With material table [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5hed3?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-multiple-header-footer-example.ts).

I suspect that it doesnot support material design. But if anyone have a Solution Please Help me.
Thank you

[image]

Comment: What is expected output do you need ?

Comment: Same Table as it shows in my page with all default mat-table design.

Comment: Just remove `id="print-section` from table and adds seperate parent div tag to table with id="print-section" it will work for you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5hed3-nzgjtm?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-multiple-header-footer-example.html

Comment: you are right.it Does Work in Stackbitz but somehow i changed it in my component local it still gives me blank page. Scss is Loaded but No Table is shown.strange :)

Comment: try to rebuild your application. May be this work

Comment: I did and also Debug. if i remove [useExistingCss] then it shows table without any Css but with the [useExistingCss] it's Blank Page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239029/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-tiana).

Comment: The below answer by @Developer is absolutely correct! You just need to give the printable section id to the parent element...:)

It worked for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `id = "print-section" from table tag and adds new parent div to table tag with` id = "print-section"` , This is how it works here.

Demo in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5hed3-nzgjtm?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-multiple-header-footer-example.html)

```
<div id="print-section">
  <table
    mat-table
    [dataSource]="transactions"
    class="mat-elevation-z8 colorTest" >
      .........
   </table>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

if above is not working then you can add your custom css with useExistingCss too just like below..

```
  <button mat-button  color="primary" printSectionId="print-section" 
     ngxPrint [useExistingCss]="true" styleSheetFile="assets/custom.scss">
     PrintWithCustomScss
 </button>
```

and then you have to put your custom css file inside asset folder.